# ubuntu/linux system admin courses or video tutorials

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tutorial

Are there any video type tutorial sites that teach one how to admin a linux/ubuntu server?

My goal is to able to administer a server for subversion/git repositories (for thousands of users).

I was really hoping there was something like linda/peepcode but for server admining.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like that:

- [LinuxCBT | UnixCBT](http://www.linuxcbt.com/demos.php#debian4x_demos)

Ubuntu is similar to Debian, so it is for you.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a long time since I've put together a ["linux from scratch"](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) system; but I learned a great deal from doing it and recommend it to anyone wanting to learn more about linux.

It looks like someone has put together a youtube collection outlining the process:

[Linux From Scratch 6.5 Video Tutorial #1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-W3Cn6R0jWk&feature=channel)

Obligatory message:

- You do not need to know how to put together a linux system from scratch in order to administrate it
- you are probably looking for information more directed to the applications you are looking to support: subversion & git

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is such a thing, I have never seen something like that at least.

You could start by installing Ubuntu on a machine and start experimenting for yourself, to learn the basics (and a bit more, depending on how interested you are). There are a lot of guides for various things on the internet though, just do a Google search for what you want to know and someone has usually written about it.
Just set up some small goals (setting up a mail or web server for example) and don't give up until you accomplished them.

Another option is to take some classes/trainings in Linux system administration, there should be a whole lot of them if you look around.

Comment: +1 I think hands-on is the way to go.  I have been a Windows admin forever, but just got into Ubuntu (server).  I installed it on a spare machine months ago and have had a great time learning!

Comment: @cop1152: Question was about "any video type tutorial"

Answer (score 0):

I have found the ubuntu forums extremely useful in solving my ubuntu problems. I also agree with setting up a  machine (real or virtual) using the os. There's nothing like doing it to make stuff stick in your head.